# Create a startup script from Powershell on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, scripting, windows-scripting

I'm working on an installation script of certain software I am developing. Installation of the software on a remote server requires a certain startup script to run on each boot.

I'm writing a powershell script so I'm looking for a way to create a start up script from powershell
I have the batchfile ready to execute I just need to run it on each boot of the remote server

I couldn't find any resources on Google therefore I am asking here if anyone could achieve such a result

Comment: Have a look at the Microsoft documentation for RUN and RUN ONCE registry keys. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can start a command procedure from PowerShell with the following code. Replace the path and file with your own information.

```
C:Pathfile.bat
```

Once you’ve called your batch file, you can customize it to the task at hand. For example…

If you want to capture the output of the .bat file, you can use:

```
$out = C:Pathfile.bat
```

If you want to start a process with your .bat file, you can use the PowerShell start-process cmdlet:

```
start-process C:Pathfile.bat
```

And, if you if you want to control cmd.exe, you can use this:

```
start-process "cmd.exe" "/c C:Pathfile.bat"
```

The start-process cmdlet is a standard PowerShell cmdlet, so anyone can use it. JAMS users leverage it regularly and combine it with JAMS specific cmdlets in our PowerShell snap-in to add intelligent automation to batch files.

Place it in this path:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\startup.cmd
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that does not work per user, I want the startup script to run for any user that logs on not a specific one.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the way you can create a startup script using powershell. This will create a startup script. Everytime you restart your machine, the script will execute

```
$TaskAction1 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\scripts\Config.ps1"
$TaskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$TaskPrincipal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $TaskAction1 -Trigger $TaskTrigger -Principal $TaskPrincipal -TaskName "Config" -Description "Config Script"
```

Answer (score -1):

To run your script on each boot of the remote server, do following settings on remote server.

1. open task scheduler (Win+R and enter command
       "%windir%\system32\taskschd.msc /s"
2. Action --> Create Task
3. Select required options in 'General' tab
4. Click on 'Triggers'-->New --> Begin the task: select 'At Startup'
   from dropdown list.
5. Click on 'Actions' --> New --> Action: 'Start a Program' -->
       Settings: path to your script.

To configure point number 5 you can take help on google.